# How do I get my JSON decoder to work properly?

Tags: python, json, api, testing, websocket

I was working on API testing, and I tried everything but it would not print the JSON file into a string. I was wondering if it was the website I was testing the API requests from as I kept getting a 406 error. I even tried taking code from online that shows how to do this but it still would not print and it would give the error listed below. Here I give the code I used and the response Pycharm's console gave me.

```
import json
import requests

res = requests.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
data = json.loads(res.text)
data = json.dumps(data)
print(data)
print(type(data))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/johnc/PycharmProjects/API_testing/api_testing.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = json.loads(res.text)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST API's vary widely in the types of requests they will accept. 406 means that you didn't give enough information for the server to format a response. You should include a user agent because API's are frequently tweaked to deal with the foibles of various http clients and specifically list the format of the output you want. Adding acceptable encodings lets the API compress data. Charset is a good idea. You could even add a language request but most API's don't care.

```
import json
import requests

headers={"Accept":"application/json",
    "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "Accept-Charset":"utf-8", 
    "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language":"en-US"} # or your favorite language
res = requests.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees", headers=headers)
data = json.loads(res.text)
data = json.dumps(data)
print(data)
print(type(data))
```

The thing about REST API's is that they may ignore some or part of the header and return what they please. Its a good idea to form the request properly anyway.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot, my lack of understanding of API's what caused this issue. I had to research a bit more, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The default Python User-Agent was being probably blocked by the hosting company.

You can setup any string or search for a real device string.

```py
res = requests.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees", headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
```

Comment: Thanks, this provided me the format that would help me retrieve the data.

Answer (score -1):

It's you, your connection or a proxy. Things work just fine for me.

```
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
>>> res.raise_for_status()  # would raise if status != 200
>>> print(res.json())  # `res.json()` is the canonical way to extract JSON from Requests
{'status': 'success', 'data': [{'id': '1', 'employee_name': 'Tiger Nixon', 'employee_salary': '320800', ...
```

Comment: Not sure, that wan't me. I am puzzled why it worked for you, though. REST api's are all over the map in what they accept but unless requests is adding a header itself, shouldn't your request be the same as mine? Puzzling.